# Isomorph vector space such that X complete and Y not

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, isometry, complete-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $X,Y$ be some isomorph vector spaces and let $X $ be a Banach space. If this isomorphism is isometric $Y $ is complete, too.
Could someone provide an example such that $Y $ is not complete?

Comment: Both $X$ and $Y$ need a metric for your question to make sense.

Comment: If $X$ is a Banach space , $Y$ a normed linear space and if there exists a isomorohism $T:X \to Y$  which is onto $Y$ such that $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are both continuous then $Y$ is necessarily complete. Is this what you intended to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=C\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$ and $Y=\{f\in F\mid f\text{ is differentiable and }f(0)=0\}$. Then$$\begin{array}{rccc}D\colon&Y&\longrightarrow&X\\&f&\mapsto&f'\end{array}$$is a vector space isomorphism. However, $X$ is complete, whereas $Y$ isn't (in both cases, with respect to the $\sup$-norm).